# angular table mat sorting arrow not showing in first load

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

why is that when I assign or put  the sortParams and sortDirs inside ngOnit the sort arrow is showing and working but when I put or assign it inside getUserData() it does not work ? it it because of the async ? thank would be appreciated.

the issue is the mat sort header arrow is not showing then I assign the sorting inside getUserData but it works when I do it in ngOnit . But i need to assign in getUserData .

[image: table screenshot]

```
   this.requestsListTable.sortParams = ['requestTitle']
        this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = ['asc'];
```

#ts code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currAcct = JSON.parse(this._storageService.getCurrAcct());

    this.isProjectTeamData = this.currAcct.isProjectTeamData;
    this.isRequestIntakeReadOnly = this.currAcct.isRequestIntakeReadOnly;
    this.isRequestIntakeSubmitter = this.currAcct.isRequestIntakeSubmitter;
    this.requestsListTable.dataSource = new MatMultiSortTableDataSource(this.sort, this.CLIENT_SIDE);
    // this.sort = new MatMultiSort();
    this.requestsListTable.nextObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.requestsListTable.sortObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.requestsListTable.previousObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.requestsListTable.sizeObservable.subscribe(() => { this.initRequestsList(); });
    this.getProjectIntakeDepartments();
    this.getRequestsCount();
    this.checkPageAccess();
    this.getUserData();
    this.requestsListTable.sortParams = ['requestTitle']
    this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = ['asc'];
  }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent<any>(this.searchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map((event) => event.target.value),
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(async (search) => {
          // this.setDefaultFilters();
          this.requestsListTable.pageIndex = 0;
          this.initRequestsList();
        })
      )
      .subscribe({ complete: noop });
  }

initRequestsList() {
    const currAcct = JSON.parse(this._storageService.getCurrAcct());

    const sortKey = (this.requestsListTable.sortParams.length > 0) ? this.requestsListTable.sortParams : ['requestTitle'];
    const sortOrder = (this.requestsListTable.sortDirs.length > 0) ? this.requestsListTable.sortDirs : ['asc'];
    
    const isMyRequests = (this.selectedOption === '1') ? currAcct.userId : null;
    
    this.isLoading = true;

    console.log('sortKey', sortKey)
    console.log('sortOrder', sortOrder)


    this._projectIntakeService
      .getRequestsList(
        currAcct.accountId,
        isMyRequests,
        sortKey,
        sortOrder,
        this.searchInput.nativeElement.value || '',
        this.requestsListTable.pageIndex + 1,
        this.requestsListTable.pageSize,
        this.selectedDepartmentIds,
        this.selectedStatusIds
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this._notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          this.firstItemPosition = res.firstItemOnPage;
          this.lastItemPosition = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.dataSource = res.items;
          this.requestsListTable.data = res.items;
          this.lastItemOnPage = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.totalItemCount = res.totalItemCount;
        },
        complete: _.noop,
      });
  }


 getUserData() {
    this._userService.getUserProfile(this.currAcct.userId, this.currAcct.accountId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {
            const filteredAccounts = this.filterAccountsByName(res.data.userAccountDto, this.currAcct.accountName);
            this.projectIntakeSettings = JSON.parse(filteredAccounts[0].projectIntakeSettings);

            //request type
            this.selectedOption = (this.projectIntakeSettings.UserId) ? '1' : '2';

            //page
            this.requestsListTable.pageIndex = (this.projectIntakeSettings.Page) ? this.projectIntakeSettings.Page - 1 : 0
            this.requestsListTable.pageSize = (this.projectIntakeSettings.PageSize) ? this.projectIntakeSettings.PageSize : 10;


            // Check if sortKey and sortOrder are provided in projectIntakeSettings
            const sortKey = this.projectIntakeSettings.SortKey ? JSON.parse(this.projectIntakeSettings.SortKey) : ['requestTitle'];
            const sortOrder = this.projectIntakeSettings.SortOrder ? JSON.parse(this.projectIntakeSettings.SortOrder) : ['asc'];

            // Assign sortParams and sortDirs
            this.requestsListTable.sortParams = sortKey;
            this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = sortOrder;

          }
        },
        err => {
          AppUtils.errorHandler(err, this._notificationService, null);
        }
      )

  }
```

#html code

```
<div class="table-center mat-elevation-z8">
                      <table
                      mat-table
                      [dataSource]="requestsListTable.dataSource"
                      matMultiSort
                      [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}"
                      (matSortChange)="requestsListTable.onSortEvent()"  
                      (contentChanged)="isLoading = false">

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="requestTitle" sticky>
                      <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestTitle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Request Title</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <div class="checkbox-container td-value-name">
                          <mat-checkbox matTooltip="{{ isNotAllowedBulk(element) ? 'Unable to batch approve' : '' }}"
                            [checked]="isSelected(element)" [disabled]="isNotAllowedBulk(element)" class="no-navigation"
                            color="primary" (change)="onChangeSelect(element, $event, 'request')"></mat-checkbox>
                          <div style="width:180px;" [matTooltip]="element.requestTitle" class="td-value-name request-title">{{
                            element.requestTitle?.length > 45 ? element.requestTitle.slice(0,45) + '...' : element.requestTitle }}</div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="requestorName">
                      <th mat-multi-sort-header="requestorName" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Requestor Name</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <div class="td-value-name">
                          {{element.requestorName}}
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </ng-container>
```

Comment: I see you are using `matMultiSort` directive, is it from Angular Material or an external library? If it is from an external library, please specify the package name.

Comment: import {MatMultiSort, MatMultiSortTableDataSource, TableData,} from 'ngx-mat-multi-sort';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons matSortHeader might not work, is because it is added to async block.

```
this.requestsListTable.sortParams = ['requestTitle']
this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = ['asc'];
```

You try to assign sortData after the component view is already rendered.

I think you can try to use detectChanges() from ChangeDetectorRef inside subscribe method to make sure that the template is re-rendered after a new value appears after fetching userProfile.

Exemple:

```
 getUserData() {
    this._userService.getUserProfile(this.currAcct.userId, this.currAcct.accountId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          if (res.isSuccess) {

             ......

            // Assign sortParams and sortDirs
            this.requestsListTable.sortParams = sortKey;
            this.requestsListTable.sortDirs = sortOrder;

            this._cd.detectChanges();
          }
        },
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I also have tried this one but the issue is still the same, how about on the html part ? do I still need to add condition to the table ?